# Trigger watching localStorage change doesn't fire in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and I am trying to write a trigger that will fire upon localStorage change and call one of the EuroPass services. I have found that the trigger only fires upon first opening my page, even though my json in the localStorage is getting changed upon me inputting new data (checked with google chrome inspector). Here is my controller:

```
CVapp.controller('CVcontroller', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function($scope, $http, $window){

$scope.CVjson = {};

$scope.$watch(function(){
  return $window.localStorage.getItem('temporary.europass.ewa.skillspassport.v3');
}, function(newjson, oldjson){
  $scope.CVjson = $window.localStorage.getItem('temporary.europass.ewa.skillspassport.v3');
  console.log('change');
});

}])
```

I use console.log to get alerted when the change happens and the console gives "change" only upon opening the page. I would appreciate any insight on what I am doing wrong. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If local storage key changing by you, then try to use some callback which will call external service.

Comment: I am not yet calling any external service, so far everything is local. Currently I am trying to make the trigger fire on every localStorage change.

Comment: I don't see any necessity for local storage change tracking via some triggers/watchers. Such trigger will be called many times. How often localstorage will change ?

Comment: Pretty often. Still, I am wondering why it doesn't work as it is.